# Pygame action when mouse 'click' on .rect?

Tags: python, mouseevent, pygame, rect

I have been writing a test function to learn how a mouse 'click' action on a pygame.rect will result in a reponse.

So far:

```
def test():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((770,430))
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(1)
    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background = background.convert()
    background.fill((250,250,250))
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    ## set-up screen in these lines above ##

    button = pygame.image.load('Pictures/cards/stand.png').convert_alpha()
    screen.blit(button,(300,200))
    pygame.display.flip()

    ## does button need to be 'pygame.sprite.Sprite for this? ##
    ## I use 'get_rect() ##
    button = button.get_rect()

    ## loop to check for mouse action and its position ##
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.mouse.get_pressed():
                ## if mouse is pressed get position of cursor ##
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                ## check if cursor is on button ##
                if button.collidepoint(pos):
                    ## exit ##
                    return
```

I have come across pages on google where people are using or are recommended to use a `pygame.sprite.Sprite` class for the images and I'm thinking that this is where my problem is from.  I have checked the pygames docs and there isn't much cohesion between methods, imho.  I am obviously missing something simple but, I thought `get_rect` would make an image in pygames be able to check if the mouse position is over it when pressed?

Edit:
    I'm thinking I need to call the `pygame.sprite.Sprite` method to make the images/rects interactive?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, if anyone is interested or is having a similar issue, this is what I needed to change.

First off, remove:

```
button = button.get_rect()
```

Then:

```
screen.blit(button, (300, 200))
```

Should be:

```
b = screen.blit(button, (300, 200))
```

This to create a `Rect` of the area of where the button is located on the screen.

From:

```
if event.type == pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
```

To:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
```

The `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` gets the state of all three mouse buttons (MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, MOUSEBUTTONUP, or MOUSEMOTION).  I also needed to add in `event.button == 1` to specify that this was the 'left-mouse' button being pressed.

Finally:

```
`if button.collidepoint(pos):`
```

To:

```
`if b.collidepoint(pos):`
```

Using `Rect` b's collidepoint method.

Answer (score 2):

I think rect method call collidepoint, not collide**r**point.
Here is the [link](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) to documentation!

Comment: Good catch I was more than likely slightly mixing together `collide*r*ect` and into `collidepoint`.  I edited to show this but, I think you could have just commented instead of making this an answer :P