# Pygame, Adding quit function to a rectangle

Tags: python, function, pygame, exit

I have a problem I can't seem to solve. I have tried to find a way to add a function like quitting a program to a rectangle in Pygame. Here is the code I have so far. I would like to add an on click quit feature to the quit box in the corner.

```
def addRect(self):
    self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (white), (300, 200, 300, 200), 2)
    pygame.display.update()


def addText(self):
    self.screen.blit(self.font.render('Quit', True, (84,84,84)), (550, 375))
    pygame.display.update()
```

I have it working with the bits above and below and it does make a "Quit" Image at the bottom corner where I need it. However, I'm again stuck on the function!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pygame action when mouse 'click' on .rect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150957/pygame-action-when-mouse-click-on-rect)

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar to this, and the way that I handled it was I made a list in the main program that had all of the "inner windows" or whatever you want to call them.  Whenever the main program received a signal from a window to close it, it deleted it from the list.

To make the signal, you will want to create a rect in the location where you want the button to be.  Make a function for the "inner window" and have it test for that rect being clicked.  If it is clicked, have the function return something like `'closed'` or whatever you want.  In the main program, say something like

```
for window in windows:
    if window.update()=='closed':
        windows.remove(window)
```

to remove any window which is closed.

EDIT:

After looking at your code a bit more in depth, it looks like how you're doing it won't work.  To add a rect, you will need to have something in your main code to store whether or not the rect is there.  To close the window, you will have to change that variable.

To check if the rect should be closed, make another rect that is where the text which should be closing the window is.  When this text is clicked, have the function return something which should be interpreted by the main code to close the window.

A basic example is shown below.

The class:

```
def update(self):
    #set up the test rect
    text=self.font.render('Quit', True, (84,84,84))
    textrect=text.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft=(550, 375)
    #see if the button is pressed
    if textrect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        return 'closed'
    #render stuff
    self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (white), (300, 200, 300, 200), 2)
    self.screen.blit(text, (550, 375))
```

Note that I combined your two original classes into one, as I don't see a reason why you would ever want the rect but not the text or vise versa.  This is a pretty simple change if you don't like it.

Also note that this will close the window if the mouse is pressed off the button, then dragged onto it.  To avoid this, you will have to pass the list gotten from `pygame.event.get()` as an argument for the `update` function, and search through it for a `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event, but this would cause unnecessary complications that I tried to avoid.

The main code:

```
rectOn=False
while True:
    if rectOn:
        if rect.update()=='closed':
            rectOn=False
```

To make the rect appear again after it has been closed, simply set `rectOn` to `True`.

Comment: I have understood slightly could you just explain in a bit more detail please, im slightly new to pygame and python in general

Comment: @user3033788 sorry to give you a false alarm, but it turns out that my "working" example includes 3 files and over 1,000 lines of code, because of other stuff I added to it, but the snippets of code that I gave in my answer should be enough for you to work into your code.

Answer (score 0):

A made a small example that you can work on. Instead of buttons returning something on click, they have a function assigned to the click.

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *

screen_color = (0,0,0)

class Button:
    def __init__(self,pos,action):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos)
        self.action = action
    def draw(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), self.rect)
    def checkCollide(self,x,y):
        return self.rect.collidepoint(x,y)

    def do(self):
        self.action()


def action():
    global screen_color
    screen_color = (255,255,0)


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)
buttons = []

buttons.append(Button((10,10,50,50),action))

while True:
    screen.fill(screen_color)
    for button in buttons:
        button.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            for button in buttons:
                if (button.checkCollide(x,y)):
                    button.do()
```